# How to insert image through textarea or html editor?

Tags: javascript, html

i have textarea where user can input some text, and this works but the problem arises when he wants to insert the image...

if he put this for example in textarea (Thumbnail image (linked) code)

```
<a href="http://www.ultraimg.com/image/1V6n"><img src="http://ultraimg.com/images/2016/08/11/1V6n.md.jpg" alt="1V6n.jpg" border="0" /></a>
```

when he clicks save button, after that it show the same img code, but there is no image...

so i started to use ckeditor but the situation is the same....

so please tell what i need to ?

Thank you

Comment: That is because textarea is for text (Hint is in the name).

Comment: Just like @SaucedApples said, textarea is for text. What you could do is make a `<div>` with `contenteditable="true"` to add images or text or whatever inside it

Comment: You can checkout the following editor: http://demos.wijmo.com/WidgetExplorer/explore.html?widget=Editor&sample=Overview

Comment: "when he clicks save button, after that it show the same img code" — That's to do with what you do with the HTML after it is saved, not how you type it in in the first place.

Comment: So also  with ckeditor cant do that?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of [textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea),  you may use [contentEditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/contentEditable).

For limitations and usage take a look to the reported links.

This is an example:

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
    <a href="http://www.ultraimg.com/image/1V6n"><img src="http://ultraimg.com/images/2016/08/11/1V6n.md.jpg" alt="1V6n.jpg" border="0" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok. I will try that. Thank you